# enum, classes, namespaces and long names

Tags: c++, enums

From what I understand, enums that relates to a class should be declared inside the class, like this:

```
namespace Sensors {
class MySensor {
 public:
     enum class SensorStatus {
         kSensorActive,
         kSensorInactive
     }
     SensorStatus GetCurrentStatus(void);
};
}
```

The problem I'm having with this, is that it leads to the following code in another part of the program.

```
 Sensors::MySensor::SensorStatus current_status = mySensor.GetStatus();
 switch (current_status):
     case Sensors::MySensor::SensorStatus::kSensorActive:  // 47 characters!
          printf("Sensor is active.");
          break;
     case Sensors::MySensor::SensorStatus::kSensorInactive:  // 49 characters!
          printf("Sensor is inactive.");
          break;
```

I appreciate that its very clear what `kSensorActive` and `kSensorInactive` refers to, no ambiguity there. But if you try to follow a style guide that specifies 80 characters, we end up with a lot of line breaks, which reduces clarity, IMHO. One example of a long line comes if we have a function that takes two different enumerators; `MyFunction(NamespaceA::MyFirstClass::MyFirstEnum::AnEnumerator, NamespaceB::MySecondClass::MySecondEnum::ADifferentEnumerator)` - a whopping 127 characters.

Is it common with these long names or am I missing something?

Comment: You can always alias types: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you repeat stuff:

The name `kSensorActive` doesn't have to say `Sensor` if you already specified that it's a `SensorStatus` in the name. Or you could remove `Sensor` from `SensorStatus` if it's inside `MySensor`. Maybe both.

The idea behind wrapping things inside classes and namespaces is that you CAN use the same name over and over again, for something that is "the same sort of thing", rather than having completely unique names throughout.

You can also, locally, change the names with `using`, something like this

```
using Status = Sensors::MySensor::SensorStatus;
```

and then us `Status::kSensorActive` where you previously used the long thing.

Comment: Very true. Coming from a C-world I too easy use long names for enums, since C doesn't have namespaces the same way, so I would have to name the enum and its constants things like `MySensorStatus` and `kMySensorStatusInactive`. With C++'s namespaces, this is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

To reduce the length without reducing the overall scope clarity you have at least 2 options:

1. Alias types ie. `using Status = Sensors::MySensor::SensorStatus;`
2. A `typedef` ie. `typedef Sensors::MySensor::SensorStatus Status2;`

Use these inside the scope of this function so it is local and the ambiguous name doesnt spread throughout the code. [Here is a live example.](https://ideone.com/uPzNOb)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could use `using` for other than namespaces! (Which I've been told not to)

Comment: @T'n'E You should have been told not to use `using` in **header** files, where the `using`clause can spread through all the code, as this answer is commenting. But it is perfectly fine to use it inside functions or even inside the .cpp, where its scope can be perfectly controlled.

Comment: Maybe we mean different uses, but [Google's styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Namespaces) doesn't make a distinction where you place `using namespace foo` - which was the only use I was aware of before this. :) I can see the difference when using it the way described above (and contained to .cpp-files).